# Is it possible to run PDAL without Conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, pdal, python-3.7

PDAL looks like a fantastic library but for some reason when I install Anaconda, it breaks a bunch of dependencies\paths.  Is it possible to use PDAL without having Anaconda (Miniconda) installed? If so, can you outline the steps?  This is where I am getting my steps now - [Windows](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/) 10 It may be stemming from the "*Register Anaconda as your default Python*" checkbox.  I would rather not do that.

**UPDATE**
Things are working well in the OSGEO4Shell and I was able to run a pipeline with

```
pdal pipeline testpipe1.json

{
    "pipeline":[
     {
        "type":"readers.las",
        "filename":"F:\\MP02-MP25\\LAS\\XXX5_RGB(1564).las"
      },
      {
        "type":"filters.crop",
        "a_srs": "EPSG:4326",
        "polygon":"POLYGON ((
              -90.28151392936705 38.64088326179908,
              -90.28208792209625 38.64059415029273,
              -90.2816641330719 38.64016257587423,
              -90.28008699417114 38.640112295190406,
              -90.27978658676147 38.64051453967314,
              -90.28035521507263 38.640879071785584,
              -90.28151392936705 38.64088326179908
              ))"
      },
      {
        "type":"writers.las",
        "a_srs": "EPSG:4326",
        "filename":"F:\\MP02-MP25\\LAS\\XXX5_RGB(1564)T.las"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OSGeo4W setup -> Advanced Install, you can select the PDAL Library and install on a QGIS instalation and use in Python-Qgis standalone or in OSGeo4W Shell.
[image: PDAL Lib in OSGeo4w]

Comment: Error from the OSGEOShell - 'The code execution cannot proceed because gdal203.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.'

Comment: Same solution, put gdal203 in search of OSGeo4W Setup

Comment: Yes - I typed 'setup' into the OSGEOShell and did exactly that. Then typed pdal -h and it is working !  Thanks  I did try and pip install GDAL -U but that was an error also.

Comment: In OSGeo4W Shell, you can use GDAL Tools too

Comment: If you "python-qgis" in OSGeo4W Shell, you can import osgeo and gdal

Comment: pdal info works but none of the PDAL pipeline examples work.  All end with pdal pipeline testpipe1.json
PDAL: in Json::Value::resolveReference(key, end): requires objectValue

Comment: I still cannot get pdal to install with pip install pdal in OSGEO4W shell.

Comment: After install in Setup of OSGeo4W, doesnt need install with pip.