# Using PDAL in custom QGIS plugin

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, pdal, conda

Is there a way to use PDAL in the custom QGIS plugin without conda (especially in Windows)? The only solution I'm using now is conda environment activation and launching QGIS from this environment which is uncomfortable

Comment: duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387842/is-it-possible-to-run-pdal-without-conda ?