# Importing PDAL inside QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, import, pdal

I have some functions using PDAL in Python that I'd like to integrate inside a QGIS plugin. This plugin must be easy to install on different OS (Windows, Linux).

However, even if PDAL is used by QGIS to display point clouds, I didn't find a way to access and use it with a plugin. I have to create a conda environment with QGIS and PDAL, activate it and launch QGIS from this environment which is uncomfortable and not an easy way for QGIS users.

Is there a simpler solution to using PDAL in a QGIS plugin?

**Related questions:**

- [Development of a plugin which depends on an external Python library](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/196002/development-of-a-plugin-which-depends-on-an-external-python-library)
- [Using PDAL in custom QGIS plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403803/using-pdal-in-custom-qgis-plugin)